# Use subquery multiple times

Tags: mysql, if-statement, subquery, sum

I need some help with a view.

I have 2 tables that I need to "merge" together.

First table contains info about products (product-color-size), and the other tables has info about stock, sold, avilable (quantity) etc on product-season-color-size niveau.

I need my view to return available pr product.
The same product-color-size can be multiple times (It can be on multiple seasons), and therefore I can't just sum on ex available.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT
    SUM((
        SELECT
            SUM(products_details.available)
        FROM
            products_details
        WHERE
            products_details.product_id = products.id
    )) AS available
FROM
    products
```

But, this will not work. If one size has 6 in available and another has -5, the query will return 1 available. But, I actually got 6, I can sell.

Therefore I need to do some adjustments

```
SELECT
    SUM((
        SELECT
            SUM(
                IF(
                    products_details.available > 0,
                    products_details.available,
                    0
                )
            )
        FROM
            products_details
        WHERE
            products_details.product_id = products.id
    )) AS available
FROM
    products
```

But, this will also not work. If the size has 6 in available on one season, and -5 on another, the query will return 6 available. But, these two rows I need to sum, because it's the same product. Therefore it needs to return 1 available.

So, I came up with

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        IF(
            (
                SELECT
                    SUM(
                        IF(
                            products_details.available > 0,
                            products_details.available,
                            0
                        )
                    )
                FROM
                    products_details
                WHERE
                    products_details.product_id = products.id
            ) > 0,
            (
                SELECT
                    SUM(
                        IF(
                            products_details.available > 0,
                            products_details.available,
                            0
                        )
                    )
                FROM
                    products_details
                WHERE
                    products_details.product_id = products.id
            ),
            0
        )
    ) AS available
FROM
    products
```

But, that will be very (!!) slow. Can I somehow use the same subquery multiple times? So I can use it in the If-statement, and if it's positive I can use the same value to use in the sum?

It's pretty complex, but I hope someone can help me

/Mads

## Edit

I just found out, that I can write

```
SELECT
    SUM((
        SELECT
            IF(
                SUM(products_details.available) > 0,
                SUM(products_details.available),
                0
            )
        FROM
            products_details
        WHERE
            products_details.product_id = products.id
    )) AS available
FROM
    products
```

That could work okay

## Edit2

I found a new and much quicker way to write it, and it works just fine :-)

```
SELECT
    SUM(GREATEST(0,(
        SELECT
            SUM(products_details.available)
        FROM
            products_details
        WHERE
            products_details.product_id = products.id
    ))) AS available
FROM
    products
GROUP BY
    products.id
```

This is very quick - from about 10 sec to just above 1 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries are not the right tool for this job. In fact, subqueries are fairly rare in everyday SQL queries. What's more likely to be useful are `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT products.*, SUM(IF(product_details.available > 0, product_details.available, 0)) AS available
FROM products
INNER JOIN product_details ON (product_details.product_id = products.id)
GROUP BY products.id
```

This will return one row for each product with the sum of all `availability` values for that product across all rows of `products_details`.

Comment: This will not work.  
I need to SUM across seasons (the size can be on multiple seasons, but I need the SUMmed-value of it)..

I would love(!) to use join (I use them all the time), but because I need to SUM a special way, I can't use it that way

Comment: Ah, I misread that restriction. How can you identify which `product_details` record is the correct one? In your example where one has 6 and one has -5, how can I tell the 6 is the right one?

Comment: If I'm reading your samples correctly, it's just a question of zeroing out any negative values and still summing them. I've made that adjustment to my query.

Comment: I have made it simpler here :) It's a bit more complex with more where-statements in the subquery.

It's not just zeroring out. Because, I need to SUM across seasons first before I check weither it's positive.

Comment: You may want to post an example of your real data and an example of the output you'd expect. It's hard to guess what the query should be without being able to see how seasons, availability, and products interrelate.